# report class properties using BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, winforms

I start a Process and want to get the process output in order to show it on my form (winform), so I created ProgressChanged event. My problem is that from some reason I cannot get in to my progressChanged function.

My code:

```
BackgroundWorker bgWorker = null;
string pcapFilePathSniffer = "";
```

This is my class that starts the process:

```
public class Tshark
{
    public int _interfaceNumber;
    public string _pcapPath;
    Process _tsharkProcess;
    public int _packetsCount;
    public string _packet;        
    public string _tsharkPath = @"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe";
    public delegate void dlgPackProgress(int progress);
    public event dlgPackProgress evePacketProgress;

    public Tshark(int interfaceNumber, string pcapPath)
    {
        _interfaceNumber = interfaceNumber;
        _pcapPath = pcapPath;
    }

    public void startTheCapture()
    {
        try
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            _tsharkProcess = new Process();
            _tsharkProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe";
            //_tsharkProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(" -i " + _interfaceNumber + " -c " + int.MaxValue + " -w " + _pcapPath);
            _tsharkProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-i " + 2);
            _tsharkProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);
            _tsharkProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            _tsharkProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            _tsharkProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            _tsharkProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            _tsharkProcess.Start();
            StreamReader myStreamReader = _tsharkProcess.StandardOutput;                

            while (!myStreamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                evePacketProgress(_packetsCount);
                _packet = myStreamReader.ReadLine();
                list.Add(_packet);
                _packetsCount++;

                private void OnPacketProgress(int packet)
                {
                  var handler = evePacketProgress;
                  if (handler != null)
                  {
                     handler(packet);
                  }
                }
            }         

            _tsharkProcess.WaitForExit();                

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

start button who start to process:

```
private void btnStartCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bgWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgWSniffer_ProgressChanged);
    bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
        (s3, e3) =>
        {
            tshark = new Tshark(2, pcapFilePathSniffer);
            tshark.startTheCapture();

            tshark.evePacketProgress += new Tshark.dlgPackProgress(
                (packet) =>
                {
                    bgWorker.ReportProgress(packet, tshark);
                });
        });

    bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
        (s3, e3) =>
        {

        });

    bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

ProgressChanged function:

```
private void bgWSniffer_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    tshark = e.UserState as Tshark;
    listBoxPacketsSnifferTab.Text += tshark._packet;
    lblPacketsReceived2.Text = tshark._packetsCount.ToString("#,##0");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should raise `Tshark.evePacketProgress` event from `startTheCapture` to call `BackgroudWorker.ReportProgress`. Something like this:

```
private void OnPacketProgress(int packet)
{
  var handler = evePacketProgress;
  if (handler != null)
  {
     handler(packet);
  }
}

public void startTheCapture()
{
        // your code here

        while (!myStreamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            _packet = myStreamReader.ReadLine();
            list.Add(_packet);
            OnPacketProgress(_packetsCount++);
        }

        // your code here
}
```

Comment: can you show me please how and where to use it ? cause after write evePacketProgress(_packetsCount); in startTheCapture function before _tsharkProcess.WaitForExit(); even than i cannot get in to my rogressChanged function (i update my code)

Comment: @DanaYeger: if you want to report about execution progress, you should report it in the execution loop. I've updated the answer.

Comment: where should i put the finction private void OnPacketProgress(int packet) ?

Comment: @DanaYeger: look at my answer carefully. Put into the while loop.

Comment: i to while (!myStreamReader.EndOfStream) ? compilations errors

Comment: @DanaYeger: what kind of errors? Please, update the question with the current version of code.

Comment: i update my code with your code, i don't think private void OnPacketProgress sould be inside while (!myStreamReader.EndOfStream)

Comment: @DanaYeger: of course, it shouldn't. :) It's a separate private method within `Tshark` class. But **call** to OnPacketProgress should be inside the `while` loop.

Comment: OK thanks now it's working inside the class but what about my bgWSniffer_ProgressChanged who should update my label on my form ?